# vbScript opens up excel but doesn't load macro/modules?

Tags: vba, vbscript, excel, excel-2010

I m in a very weird situation. I created a vbs script that would open my excel file. I had defined vba code in WorkBook_open method. I thought creating a vbs script to open up my excel would invoke my workBook_open method and execute the vba code inside it. But I was wrong. Below is my vbs code.

```
filePath = "E:\data_extracts\mydata.xlsm"
Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
oExcel.Workbooks.Open(filepath)
oExcel.Visible = True
oExcel.Run "RefreshDataFromIQY"
oExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Save
oExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Close
oExcel.Quit
Set oExcel = Nothing
```

On debugging, it fails at oExcel.Run "RefreshDataFromIQY" saying either macros are not available or disabled. Hence it is the code just opnes up excel application successfully and that's all it does. I have macro codes in module1, module2. How/where do I write to execute my macros in vbs script below. My macros/modules have to be executed in sequence and some of my macros are recorded macros. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Thanks for your input Scott. Here's what I made changes to my code

```
Dim oExcelApp
Dim oExcelWkb

set oExcelApp = createobject("Excel.Application")
set oExcelWkb = oExcelApp.Workbooks.Open("\\myserver\data_extracts\TestTOPTMay307.xlsm")
oExcelWkb.Close True
oExcelApp.Quit
```

However on running it from command line, its giving me runtime error Object required: 'Close'. Any idea why? Why is it failing to Close? What am i doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: just a crossing all the t's thought -> do you have your Excel app set to trust VBA?

Comment: 2 more thoughts -. 1) you could try "E:\data_extracts\mydata.xlsm!RefreshDataFromIQY" or "E:\data_extracts\mydata.xlsm!Module1.RefreshDataFromIQY" 2)If "RefreshDataFromIQY" is a private sub / function, it may not work in this (probably doesn't apply to you, but just thought I would add it in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tested your code against a dummy file I made. It worked when I placed the code inside a  module and left it as public. However, when I put into a private module -> like worksheet level module, I got the error you got.

However, when I referenced the private object, the code ran through. So my answer to you is to replace

```
oExcel.Run "RefreshDataFromIQY"
```

With

```
oExcel.Run "[yourClassName].RefreshDataFromIQY"
```

Also, I placed a workbook_event in my file as well. The event triggered successfully on open, so if there is trouble with yours, it's most likely in the code inside the event.

Comment: Scott I made edits to my post. Please see above. Thanks for your guidance. :0

Comment: code works fine for me. check and make sure your path name is correct. Also, if you have a macro running on the workbook_open event, you may want to be a timer statement into the vbs code to wait for X seconds, so the macro in the workbook can process. Also, for future reference, your 2nd question seems like a different problem from your first. It's best practice to accept an answer to your question, than post a new question if it's another separate issue.

Comment: Thanks Scott. The problem was I was forcing 'Close' in my vbscipt whereas the macro that gets executed under Workbook_Open automatically saves and closes. So I just had to omit oExcelWkb.Close True and it worked. Thanks. In reference to this thread, I wil be posting a new thread(new problem I ran into). Thanks again.

Comment: + 1 For seeing this through :) @Nemo: `gets executed under Workbook_Open automatically saves and closes.` If you wouldn't have ignored my comment then we would have solved this earlier :) I ended up finally deleting my comment :)