# Open Excel and Run Macro using VBScript

Tags: excel, vba, vbscript

I'm trying to use this VBScript to open a file and run a macro. Ideally I'd open it from my personal workbook, but happy to run from anywhere as a compromise.

```
Option Explicit

On Error Resume Next

RunExcelMacro

Sub RunExcelMacro()

Dim xlApp
Dim xlBook

If CheckAppOpen("excel.application")  Then
       'MsgBox "App Loaded"
        Set xlApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")   
Else
        ' MsgBox "App Not Loaded"
        Set  xlApp = CreateObject(,"Excel.Application")   
End If

xlApp.visible = True
set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open ("C:\Users\....\PERSONAL.xlsb", 0, True)
xlApp.Run "Module1.My Macro"
xlApp.Quit()

xlBook = Nothing
xlApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

The script does not open any Excel file, independent of if it being on a server or in my C drive.

There's been a [fair](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2050505/way-to-run-excel-macros-from-command-line-or-batch-file) number of [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10707574/vbscript-opens-up-excel-but-doesnt-load-macro-modules) on this. I did some [research](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/4b3e0c49-7fb7-4568-892a-00ba14188834/excel-error-when-opening-file-through-vb-script?forum=ITCG).

I tried:

```
Set xlApp = GetObject("Excel.Application")  
Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
```

as well as

```
Dim Filename as string
Filename = "C:/....."
set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open (Filename)
```

I've tried opening .xls, .xlsm, .xlsb all to no avail.

I am not getting any error messages. The cmd console opens and then closes with this

> Microsoft (R) Windows Script Host Version 5.8
>   Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Comment: Remove `On Error Resume Next` and run this from a cmd window (`cscript.exe your.vbs`) to see the error messages.

Comment: Thanks! 
I'm now getting :
" Microsoft VBScript runtime error: Type mismatch"
for the line:
Set xlApp = CreateObject(, "Excel.Application")

Comment: Remove the leading comma: `Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")`

Comment: Wizard, it's now opening the file, but the macro isn't running. 
"Microsoft Excel: Cannot run the macro 'Macro1.My_macro'. The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled."

Comment: Macronames cannot have spaces in them, you are trying to run a macro named "My Macro", which is an illegal name for a sub.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @AlexK. Turned out to be a comma in the wrong place.

Also thanks to [this post](http://www.visualbasicscript.com/Run-a-macro-stored-in-personalxlsb-via-vb-script-m101486.aspx) changed:

```
 xlApp.Run "Module1.MyMacro"
```

to:

```
   xlApp.Run xlBook.name & "!Module1.MyMacro"
```